# How can I use for loop to make a new FILE in each /home directory except /home/lost+found

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, terminal

```
#!/bin/sh
for file in /home/*
do
if [ "{$file}" != "/home/lost+found" ]
then
    touch $file/FILE1
done
```

What I want to achieve is that I go through all the /home/ directories and make in each ona a *FILE* except in */home/lost+found* . What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Typos: `{$file}` should be `$file` (or `${file}`).  `done` should be `fi; done`.

Comment: And `touch $file/FILE1` should be `touch "$file"/FILE1`  (or `touch "$file/FILE1"`).

Answer (score 1):

Not much, you're missing the `fi` that terminates the if-statement, and `{$file}` expands to `{/home/somedir}`, with literal braces. The parameter expansion with braces is `${file}`, i.e. the dollar sign comes outside the braces.

In addition, the pattern `/home/*` will match all files (not just directories), so you'll get errors from `touch` if there are any. There might not be many in `/home`, but it's easy to change the pattern to `/home/*/` which should only match directories. the traling slash will then be part of the variable, so take that into account in the comparison. (Alternatively, also test `[ -d "$file" ]`.)

Also, in general, you want to quote `"$file"`. Or perhaps `dir` would be more appropriate here.

```
#!/bin/sh
for dir in /home/*/ ; do
    if [ "$dir" != "/home/lost+found/" ] ; then
       touch "$dir/FILE1"
    fi
done
```

Comment: It works. Thank you. Really interesting when I put {$dir} it doesnt work, but when I do just the "$dir" it works.
Anyway, tnx;..

Comment: @ImTrying, oh dear, I was sloppy when reading that. `{$file}` would indeed give you literal braces around the variable value, `${file}` is the variable expansion. (`$file` is the same as long as there's no word characters immediately after.) There's no need for the braces here, so I just removed them without noticing they were misplaced.